# Make Logitech G502 mouse do nothing in certain applications

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, logitech-mouse

I bought a Logitech G502 mouse and installed software from [here](http://www.logitech.com/support/g502). But when I opened it up to customize my mouse buttons, there was not an option to make the mouse button do nothing in a certain app. (Example: There a game called Ballistic on Kongregate that I play, [link to the game here](http://www.kongregate.com/games/aquiris/ballistic), I want to use a certain key to do an action in that game, but the default is "back" for that button, which brings me to the previous page I was on. Is there a way to make the button do nothing but still work in the game?

Note: Logitech Setpoint doesn't work for me

Comment: so you installed `Logitech Gaming Software`? Actually this supports different profiles for games. I can't check it right now but i'm also pretty sure you can assign "do nothing" to mouse buttons there.

Comment: I can't. There isn't an option (that I saw) to assign "do nothing". There was just "unassign" but then the computer gets no input at all from that button

Comment: You are right, i checked it. Wouldn't it be a workaround to unassign this button only for this game profile?

Comment: I still want to button to have an input but no actually do anything

Comment: @John Did you ever figure it out? I'm using the thumb buttons for push-to-talk capabilities, and I'd really like them to stop going back/forward when I'm trying to talk to people. Disabling them just means there's no input at all.

Comment: @Ellesedil I gave up on solving it a while ago. However, I think it might be possible to have a program like Autohot key intercept the button press?

Comment: I think I have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Logitech G903.  The approach I am suggesting should work for the G502 as well, as G HUB works with the G502.

You can click on the key binding or the white call on the button to get a menu that allows you do disable the button.  If you disable the button, it will only be disabled for that profile, and other profiles can use the button.

[image: Showing G HUB menu disabling a button]

Answer (score 0):

So, the specific problem I was trying to solve was that I use the back and forward buttons on the side of my mouse for push-to-talk keybinds on my various voice communication software while gaming. This led to instances where I'd press back to talk, and then whatever window I had active would receive a back command and execute it as applicable. So, if I was alt-tabbed to a web page while talking, I'm suddenly looking at a very different page, like perhaps my home page. Not great.

[image: Logitech G Hub window with keybind assignments]

Enter the F23 and F24 "keys". Logitech G Hub apparently recongizes F keys, at least on my laptop, up to F24. Most computers/keyboards only have F1-F12 keys, with perhaps a function key to get another 12 keybinds. For my configuration, however, I don't have any obvious functionality assigned to F23 and F24 despite having some functionality with `fn-F12` that turns off my keyboard backlighting. So now, instead of sending a "Back" command, I'm now sending a F24 keystroke. Now when setting up my voice comm push-to-talk, rebinding them now associates it with a typically unused input, and ends up being configured as "Unknown" (Mumble), "UNK135" (Discord), or "135" (TeamSpeak). So I now have the behavior I seek where the key is usable for a specific task, but not in a way that my game/browswer/software normally interpret as a keybind that is typically used.

Hopefully this helps and gets you whatever functionality you were trying to find.